# Output one more letter with each click in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a test, and need a hint function.

When the user clicks on hint the first letter of the answer has to be written in the input field. If he clicks again, the second letter is added etc.

The answer is written in data-right data attribute like this:

```
<div class="question">
    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="(gehen)" data-right="gegangen" />
    <div class="res"><b></b></div>
    <a class="hint">Hint</a>
</div>
```

Question,

Whats the simplest way to do this? Basically keep adding one more letter fron the answer in data-right in the input with every click on .hint?

I think I can handle the DOM navigation, but not sure how to do the output.

Comment: so all i need to do is inspect the element to find the answer? is there money involved? :P

Comment: What should happen when the user already gave a (partial) answer?

Comment: Did you try something.. Please give your code what have you tried

Comment: @GungFoo I'm guessing not as if you press hint enough times you'll be given the answer anyway (if OS gets this to work!)

Comment: if partial answer best would be delete whole answer. otherwise it would be too complicated. answer is a single word only.

Comment: also this is language exercise, youre not supposed to cheat if you want to learn :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `.data()` method for getting the value of the `data-*` attribute and `.val()` method for setting the value:

```
$('a.hint').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.question').find('input').val(function(_, val){
        var i = val.length,
            right = $(this).data('right');

        if (right.indexOf(val) !== 0) return right.slice(0, 1); 
        return val + right.slice(i, i+1);
    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HN8gs/

Comment: Very nice, except when the user fills in some letters of his own.

Answer (score 1):

You have to read data from attribute http://jsfiddle.net/4T5Ng/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dr =  $(".input").attr("data-right").split("");
    var index = 0;
    $(".hint").click(function(){
        if(index < dr.length)
        $(".input").val($(".input").val() + dr[index]);
        index++;
    });
});
```